# React State is not updated with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

When page loaded first time, I need to get all information, that is why I am calling a fetch request and set results into State [singleCall function doing that work]
Along with that, I am connecting websocket using socket.io and listening to two events (odds_insert_one_two, odds_update_one_two), When I got notify event, I have to
check with previous state and modify some content and update the state without calling again fetch request. But that previous state is still [] (Initial).
How to get that updated state?

Snipptes

```
  const [leagues, setLeagues] = useState([]);
  
  const singleCall = (page = 1, params=null) => {

    let path = `${apiPath.getLeaguesMatches}`;
    Helper.getData({path, page, params, session}).then(response => {
      if(response) {
        setLeagues(response.results);
      } else {
        toast("Something went wrong, please try again");
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err); 
    })
  };

  const updateData = (record) => {

    for(const data of record) {
      var {matchId, pivotType, rateOver, rateUnder, rateEqual} = data;
      const old_leagues = [...leagues]; // [] becuase of initial state value, that is not updated
      const obj_index = old_leagues.findIndex(x => x.match_id == matchId);
      if(obj_index > -1) {
        old_leagues[obj_index] = { ...old_leagues[obj_index], pivotType, rateOver: rateOver, rateUnder:rateUnder, rateEqual:rateEqual};
        setLeagues(old_leagues);
      }
    }
  } 

  useEffect(() => {

    singleCall();

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001', {transports: ['websocket']});

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('socket connected:', socket.connected);
    });
    socket.on('odds_insert_one_two', function (record) {
      updateData(record);
    });

    socket.on('odds_update_one_two', function (record) {
      updateData(record);
    });

    socket.emit('get_odds_one_two');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('socket disconnected, reconnecting...');
      socket.emit('get_odds_one_two');
    });

    return () => {
        console.log('websocket unmounting!!!!!');
        socket.off();
        socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` hook is created with an empty dependency array so that it only gets called once, at the initialization stage. Therefore, if `league` state is updated, its value will never be visible in the `updateData()` func.

What you can do is assign the `league` value to a `ref`, and create a new `hook`, which will be updated each time.

```
const leaguesRef = React.useRef(leagues);

React.useEffect(() => {
  leaguesRef.current = leagues;
});
```

Update `leagues` to `leaguesRef.current` instead.

```
  const updateData = (record) => {
    for(const data of record) {
      var {matchId, pivotType, rateOver, rateUnder, rateEqual} = data;
      const old_leagues = [...leaguesRef.current]; // [] becuase of initial state value, that is not updated
      const obj_index = old_leagues.findIndex(x => x.match_id == matchId);
      if(obj_index > -1) {
        old_leagues[obj_index] = { ...old_leagues[obj_index], pivotType, rateOver: 
  rateOver, rateUnder:rateUnder, rateEqual:rateEqual};
        setLeagues(old_leagues);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried the same before, but leaguesIsLoaded never set to true.